# RDLC Report Error While Exporting Report to Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I am working on RDLC report In windows aaplication.
My data is displaying in report viewer correctly. But when I click on  export report toExcel/Word/Pdf using Reportviewer option then error blinks.

How to know what is happening inside reportviewer because till this `this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();`  line there is no error

i  found same Problem but in that there was  error on Print option
 How to fix this ??
Provide me link or any suggestion

```
 private void RDLSViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSetManifest", dtManifestReport);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by the window layout system of visual studio.

Go to Window option in Visual Studio toolbar -> Reset Windows Layout

I found other people posting about this...

After "Reset Windows Layout" the problem dissapeared.